# How to implement MS Excel style "Freeze Panes" in HTML/CSS

Tags: javascript, html, excel, css

I'm using Angular JS in an HTML5/CSS3 webapp for iPad, and I have a rather large table that needs to have both horizontal and vertical scroll, with the "freeze - pane" feature that is found on MS Excel. [image: Excel style freeze pane]

Right now, I've implemented a div based layout splitting the table into 3, a top, left and middle region as shown in the image. I'm detecting scroll on the scrollable regions (top and left), and then fixing the position of the middle region to be in sync, using Javascript. This works, but is jerky. Is there a cleaner way to implement this? I'm trying to not use any plugins because my code is already pretty heavy, but if there are lightweight slick plugins, I'm open to those as well.

TIA

Comment: Google drive spreadsheets are a great example that solves this interesting question

Answer (score 0):

I know you mentioned not to use any more plugins, but I'll throw this out there anyway. Perhaps you can try to look into Zurb Foundation's responsive table plugin: http://zurb.com/playground/projects/responsive-tables/index.html

However, their examples show the first column as fixed and non-scrollable when you are in a small browser width. I see that you want the "opposite way" applied in regards to your screenshot, so some hacking away at the code will be necessary.